# How to switch from parent window to child window and child window to parent window in testcafe,

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

.switchToWindow() is not working, getting error "Cannot find the window specified in the action parameters."

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you correctly specified parameters for the `switchToWindow(parameters)` function. You can also use `switchToParentWindow()` or `switchToPreviousWindow()`.

For more information, refer to the documentation: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows.